# Poincaré and set theory

Tags: set-theory, math-history, infinity, foundations, constructive-mathematics

What did Poincaré mean whe he said:

> Later generations will regard Mengenlehre (set theory) as a disease
>   from which one has recovered.

Apparently he also says:

> There is no actual infinity, the Cantorians have forgotten that, and
>   they have fallen into contradiction. It is true that Cantorism
>   rendered services, but that was when it was applied to a real problem
>   whose terms were clearly defined, and we could walk safely.
>   Logisticians as Cantorians have forgotten. (Poincaré 1908: 212–213;
>   1913b: 484)

Poincaré was a very good mathematician so I wonder whether there are foundational reasons for these statements. I'm particularly interested in the kinds of weaknesses he might see in set theory as a mathematical theory.

Comment: I recommend you consult [MR1084532 (92c:01028)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1084532) Jeremy Gray. *[Did Poincaré say "set theory is a disease''?](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03024067)*, Math. Intelligencer **13** (1991), no. 1, 19–22. The paper not only indicates that Poincaré did not say the famous "disease" quote, but also provides ample references describing his attitude towards set theory, which changed quite a bit through the years.

Comment: In the days of yore people were harsher in their criticism of many things we consider mathematical. Cantor wrote that infinitesimals are the work of the devil, and set theory laid part of the essential foundation for modern model theory and nonstandard analysis. So, I'd regard a lot of non-mathematical things said by the past generations as some racist statement made by your great-grandmother: not ideal, but nothing to get your knickers in a bunch over. (Regardless to what @Andrés wrote, by the way.)

Comment: For a brief overview of P's philosophy of mathematics and his objectiins to Cantorism, you can see [Poincaré: Logic and foundations: intuition and predicativity](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/poincare/#LogFouIntPre).

Comment: David Hilbert said " No one will drive us out of the paradise that (Georg) Cantor has created for us."